# Python (football games algorithm troubles)

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to write algorithm for football group stage.
for example: i have 4 teams in the stage.

```
 teams = ['team1', 'team2', 'team3', 'team4']
```

then i got an all unique pairs

```
import itertools
team_pairs = list(itertools.combinations(teams, 2))
```

my team_pairs are unique matches between teams

```
[('team1', 'team2'), ('team1', 'team3'), ('team1', 'team4'), ('team2', 'team3'), ('team2', 'team4'), ('team3', 'team4')]
```

and now. how can i create all rounds?
for example:

- round1: `('team1', 'team2') ('team3', 'team4')`
- round2: `('team1', 'team3') ('team2', 'team4')`
- round2: `('team1', 'team4') ('team2', 'team3')`

and how to do that for 6 teams or for 7 teams? 
please help!!!

mb i explained bad:

i have an 11 teams. Then i break them into groups. 
and i have:

- group1: ['team1', 'team2', 'team3', 'team4']
- group2: ['team1', 'team2', 'team3', 'team4']
- group3: ['team1', 'team2', 'team3']

in each group, the team must play with all teams in group.
lets take 1 group, teams are:

```
teams = ['team1', 'team2', 'team3', 'team4']
```

win - 3 points
draft 1 point
loose - 0 points

they can't play everybody at one time.
they are playing 3 days.

```
* first day - team1 vs team2 and team3 vs team4
* second day - team1 vs team3 and team2 vs team4
* third day - team1 vs team4 and team2 vs team3
```

then i can summ points.

But i don't actually understand how to split my group (my team_pairs) by days and what team play in what day.

Comment: Please read http://sscce.org, and provide a code example of what you've tried so far showing where you're stuck or what's wrong or that you don't understand…

Comment: Your definition of "rounds" is very unclear. What exactly do you want to achieve and how far did you get?

Comment: Rounds are match days, such that each team plays every other team in a one-leg competition of `n - 1` days and that every team plays a match in every round. (The latter is obviously only possible when there is an even number of teams. If there is an odd number of teams, there should be a dummy team. Playing against the dummy teams means: No match for that team in that round.)

Comment: generate all permutations or modulate day number in chained selection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem can be seen as an [exact cover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover_problem) problem and can be solved like a Sudoku with [Algorithm X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_Algorithm_X), of which there are [Python implementations](http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~aassaf9/python/algorithm_x.html) available on the web.

The set that needs to be covered consists of:

- a combination of each team and each match day
- every match pairing

which for four teams is:

```
A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3, C1, C2, C3, D1, D2, D3, AB, AC, AD, BC, BD, CD
```

where `B3` means team `B` plays on day `3` and `BD` means team `B` plays team `D`.

The available subsets are all match pairings combined with all match days, which for four teams is:

```
AB1: A1, B1, AB
AB2: A2, B2, AB
AB3: A3, B3, AB
AC1: A1, C1, AC
...
CD3: C3, D3, CD
```

Solving this yields a great many possible fixtures, essentially permutations of teams and match days. Pick one, order by match day and play.

There are no solutions if there is an odd number of teams. Add a null team as dummy and don't play the matches where one of the sides is the dummy.