# MatchDay Scheduler

Tags: python-2.7, scheduler

I am aiming to make a match scheduler for my local football league. All the teams in the league play each other once in a round robin format. I've started by making permutations of all possible matches and just need to schedule them in a week by week format but have got stuck as to how to do it.

Currently my code is this;

```
import itertools

teams = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"] # used numbers as an example to simplify

def fixtures():
    if len(teams) % 2 != 0: # ensuring that the odd number leagues are sorted
        teams.append("Week Off") # adding a bye option
    fixtures = list(itertools.combinations(teams, 2)) # creating the fixtures
    return fixtures # outputting the fixtures
```

I then aim to make a scheduling function to split all the fixtures into week by week fixtures but can't figure out a simply way to create the fixtures so they don't clash.

I would appreciate a poke in the right direction, thank you in advance.

Comment: Looking at this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/21369856/5960561), this seems like an exact cover problem (i.e. find all of the combinations of subcollections of fixtures which form a partition of the `teams` set)